# WAR in EAR - jboss-deployment-structure.xml ignored

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

My EAR consists out of an common-jar, an EJB-jar and a WAR. The WAR uses a spring context, so it is dependend on the spring-namespace description files in the META-INF direcotry.

My WAR/jboss-deployment-structure.xml contains

```
<module name="org.springfw">
    <imports>
        <include path="META-INF**" />
        <include path="org**" />
    </imports>
</module>
```

If i deploy the EAR and the WAR seperatly, the application works perfectly.

By deploying the same WAR inside of the EAR it fails with a ClassNotFoundException (org.spring...ContextLoaderListener).

Well, i edited my WAR/META-INF/Manifest.MF and added "Dependencies: org.springfw", the application fails on startup with:

> Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]

This means the classes are available, but not the META-INF files.

To sum it up: If i deploy a WAR inside an EAR, i can still import modules via the Manifest of the WAR (works, but cant import the META-INF directory), but the WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml will always be ignored.

EDIT:

The module descriptor is

```
 <resource-root path="spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar">
         <filter>
            <include path="META-INF**" />
            <include path="org**" />
        </filter>
 </resource-root>
```

Comment: deployment-structure must be in the top level META-INF folder, so in case of EAR it should be in the META-INF of the EAR.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, Jboss permitts only one deployment-structure.xml in the EAR?

Comment: Maybe it will ignore it, [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7#ClassLoadinginAS7-JBossDeploymentStructureFile)

Comment: My solution to a similar problem was to add the dependency to the module in the jboss-deployment-structure of the ear(top-level deployment) with export="true". Additional info: In my arquillian tests in order to be able to use the module I had to add this: war.setManifest(new StringAsset("Dependencies: some.thing\n")); when building the WebArchive (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-942).

Answer (score 1):

Specify `<sub-deployment>` in your `deployment-structure.xml`.

And as said already, this xml should be in to top level ear meta-Inf.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
 <sub-deployment name="myapp.war">
   <dependencies>
     <module name="org.javassist" export="true" />
     <module name="org.apache" export="true"/>
     <module name="org.antlr" export="true"/>
     <module name="org.dom4j" export="true"/>
     <module name="org.apache" export="true"/>
     <module name="org.hibernate" export="true"/>
   </dependencies>
 </sub-deployment>
```

See also [jboss-deployment-structure.xml does not loads the dependencies in My EAR project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859092/jboss-deployment-structure-xml-does-not-loads-the-dependencies-in-my-ear-project)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using module descriptor? https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Module+descriptors

Comment: I've added the module descriptor in my question, but META-INF is not visible.