# jboss-deployment-structure.xml does not loads the dependencies in My EAR project

Tags: java, jboss, ear

this is my jboss-deployment-structure.xml of EAR project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jboss-deployment-structure >

<deployment>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.javassist" export="true" />
        <module name="org.apache" export="true"/>
        <module name="org.antlr" export="true"/>
        <module name="org.dom4j" export="true"/>
        <module name="org.apache" export="true"/>
        <module name="org.hibernate" export="true"/>

    </dependencies>

</deployment>


</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

and EAR project have my other projects in deployment path. some are JARS and one is WAR. and my one of Project uses the dependencies in the lib of EAR project. now I m removing the jars from lib folder and added above jboss-deployment-structure.xml . I guess jars are not being loaded and gives the error of not finding the required jars.
this is the StackTrace

```
08:54:05,555 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SBOS_Online].[resteasy-servlet]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet resteasy-servlet threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userBusinessImpl' defined in class path resource [config/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userHibernateDAOImpl' while setting bean property 'userDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userHibernateDAOImpl' defined in class path resource [config/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.scs.sbos.dao.hibernate.impl.UserHibernateDAOImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The import org.hibernate.Query cannot be resolved
The import org.hibernate.Session cannot be resolved
The import org.hibernate.SessionFactory cannot be resolved
The import org.hibernate.Transaction cannot be resolved
SessionFactory cannot be resolved to a type
Session cannot be resolved to a type
Transaction cannot be resolved to a type
SessionFactory cannot be resolved to a type
Session cannot be resolved to a type
Transaction cannot be resolved to a type
SessionFactory cannot be resolved to a type
Session cannot be resolved to a type
Transaction cannot be resolved to a type
SessionFactory cannot be resolved to a type
Session cannot be resolved to a type
SessionFactory cannot be resolved to a type
Session cannot be resolved to a type
SessionFactory cannot be resolved to a type
Session cannot be resolved to a type
SessionFactory cannot be resolved to a type
Query cannot be resolved to a type
Session cannot be resolved to a type
SessionFactory cannot be resolved to a type
Query cannot be resolved to a type
Session cannot be resolved to a type
SessionFactory cannot be resolved to a type
Session cannot be resolved to a type
SessionFactory cannot be resolved to a type
Session cannot be resolved to a type
SessionFactory cannot be resolved to a type
Query cannot be resolved to a type
Session cannot be resolved to a type
SessionFactory cannot be resolved to a type
Session cannot be resolved to a type
SessionFactory cannot be resolved to a type
Query cannot be resolved to a type
SessionFactory cannot be resolved to a type
SessionFactory cannot be resolved to a type
SessionFactory cannot be resolved to a type
SessionFactory cannot be resolved to a type

 at     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:340) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:214) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:190) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:540) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
```

It means Hibernate jars are not being added, but why thats the problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A jboss-deployment-structure.xml must be defined inside of the top-level deployment. That is, if you are deploying a WAR file directly, it may contain a descriptor. If you package the WAR inside of an EAR file, you need to move the content of the descriptor and define it inside of the jboss-deployment-structure.xml of the EAR file.

You need to go with a sub-deployment:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
     <sub-deployment name="myapp.war">
       <dependencies>
         <module name="org.javassist" export="true" />
         <module name="org.apache" export="true"/>
         <module name="org.antlr" export="true"/>
         <module name="org.dom4j" export="true"/>
         <module name="org.apache" export="true"/>
         <module name="org.hibernate" export="true"/>
       </dependencies>
     </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

There is a good description of [on the JBoss Docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7)

Comment: thanks for the rply. yes I have also read that . but the problem is all those dependencies are used by my one Project which is a "JAR" and when I deploy it gives error. look at the trace plz. I hace edited the question

Comment: In this way of specifying JAR dependencies can we specify version also ?

Answer (score 1):

You should add your moudle dependencies into manifest.mf file under Deployments tag of your jar file. That should work fine.

Comment: Couple of issues I have with the manifest.mf. It quickly starts to get difficult to read if there are too many entries. The number of characters are limited.