# Wildfly is concatenating log lines

Tags: logging, jboss, wildfly, slf4j

I'm using WildFly 8.2.1 to run some web services. They were developed with CXF (3.1.6) and Spring (4.3.7). I use SLF4J (1.7.25) and Logback (1.2.3) as logging.

I'm facing an strange behavior in wildfly 'server.log'. It seems that the logs generated by my application are being embeeded into wildfly logs, as you can see into the example bellow:

```
2017-04-27 08:52:12,068 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-8) 27.04.2017 08:52:12.068 [MSC service thread 1-8] INFO  x.y.b.s.ScheduleServletListener#contextInitialized(70) - Initializing the servlet context...
2017-04-27 08:52:12,068 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-8) 27.04.2017 08:52:12.068 [MSC service thread 1-8] INFO  xx.yyy.blah.something.JNDIUtil#getProxyHost(145) - java:/app_proxyhost: 10.10.10.10
2017-04-27 08:52:12,068 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-8) 27.04.2017 08:52:12.068 [MSC service thread 1-8] DEBUG xx.yyy.blah.something.ProxyUtils#setProxy(30) - ProxyHost: 10.10.10.10
```

I tried to disable logging subsystem and exclude logging modules, but with no effect.

So my question is, how do I avoid this situation?

Comment: Show us your logback config. Maybe you have a ConsoleAppender in there?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467970/logback-on-jboss-duplicates-prefixes-and-new-lines-when-logging/42517232#42517232

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Thanks. I gave up, and instead trying to disable wildfly logging, I removed the logback files from my project and started using the one provided by the AS. If you want, put your comment as an answer so I can close my question.

Comment: Never found solution for this one ?