# Wildfly 26 logs twice

Tags: java, logback, wildfly-26

I have the following setup:

jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
      <subsystem name="logging" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender encoder pattern in logback.xml:

```
MY_LOG ------ %date{ISO8601} %-5level [%thread] \(%logger{36}\) - %msg%n
```

And Wildfly produces log messages in the following format:

10:55:28,981 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 112) MY_LOG ------ 2023-02-28 10:55:28,981 DEBUG [ServerService Thread Pool -- 112] (o.a.c.b.converters.ArrayConverter) - Converting 'java.net.URL[]' value '[Ljava.net.URL;@1436a465' to type 'java.net.URL[]'

How to get rid of the wildfly messages and keep only logback?

Comment: Solution in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467970/logback-on-jboss-duplicates-prefixes-and-new-lines-when-logging?rq=1

Comment: Yes, it's because the `ConsoleAppender` writes to `System.out` which is wrapped in a logger.