# Jboss logging to slf4j/log4j2 with Keycloak

Tags: java, wildfly, keycloak, log4j2, jboss-logging

I have a Keycloak EAR module, deployed on Keycloak 11.0. In my EAR module I want to use log4j2 logging library with slf4j. I successfully accomplished this by adding the following dependencies in the pom directly: `log4j-slf4j-impl`, `log4j-api` & `log4j-core`.

Wildfly logging dependencies are excluded by setting `add-logging-api-dependencies` to `false`. `log4j2.xml` is specified outside the packaged EAR and is referenced with `log4j.configurationFile` system property.

Now the problem. I also want Keycloak to use log4j2 but I cannot get this to work. Keycloak is using Jboss Logging wrapper which always picks up `JbossLogManager` no matter which logging provider I set - I always get either `ClassNotFoundException` or `NoClassDefFoundError`.

I realize there is a classpath problem but I am out of ideas at this point. I tried creating `log4j-slf4j-impl`, `log4j-api` & `log4j-core` Wildfly modules with the following command but I still get the same error.

```
./jboss-cli.sh --command="module add --name=org.apache.logging.log4j.log4j-api --resources=/Users/jernej/log4j-api-2.13.3.jar"
```

If I understand correctly, log4j2 should be in the classpath on Wildfly startup (when searching for `LoggerProvider`)  and Jboss Logging `findProvider` method should return `Log4j2LoggerProvider` if modules are correctly added? How can I accomplished this?

Suppose I want to use log4j2 appender, located in separate library. If I add this library as a Wildfly module this log4j2 appender can then be used by other deployments as well - e.g. keycloak-server.war?

Comment: Keycloak is a server module and not part of your deployment. Therefore it logs through the system logging as configured in the logging subsystem.

Comment: I understand. Is there any way to pass those logs to log4j2 or any other custom appender?

Comment: You can run them through any handler (appender) that extends a `java.util.logging.Handler`. https://docs.wildfly.org/20/wildscribe/subsystem/logging/custom-handler/index.html. You can't process them through log4j2-core however that itself is a log manager.

Comment: Thanks! Does this custom handler need to be installed as a module in order to be available to all deployments?

Comment: Yes any custom handler would need to be installed as a module.

Comment: @jernejl can you be more specific about how you achieved to use log4j2 in your EAR module ? For instance, where did you put the log4j2.xml exactly and what its content is ? I'm trying to achive the same but didn't succeed to make it work so far.

Comment: @FabriceG., log4j2.xml is located outside of the EAR module and is referenced with the "log4j2.configurationFile" system property. I have Fluency logging appender defined inside, nothing unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a library as a module may not necessary makes it available to your application. Have you defined the dependency to that module in the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in the `META-INF` folder of your ear file? Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.3"
                            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                            xsi:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.3 http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/jboss-deployment-structure-1_3.xsd">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.apache.logging.log4j.log4j-api" export="true"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: I tried similar thing described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243943/wildfly-10-logback. I got it working for my app but as James said in the comment above, Keycloak is not part of this deployment.